# How to query Wikidata using SPARQL for a specific property?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I'm using the Wikidata Query Service to try and get all instances within Wikidata that contain a UMLS CUI (Property P2892).

I've tried doing

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE
{
  ?item wd:P2892.
}
```

But am getting the error `Query is malformed: Encountered " "." ". "" at line 3, column 17.`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: SPARQL expects **triple** patterns, you have just a **tuple**. It should be `SELECT ?item
WHERE
{
  ?item wd:P2892 ?cui .
}`

Comment: Also see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2892

Comment: And also `wdt:P`, not `wd:P` in predicate position, see https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format.

Comment: true, should be `SELECT ?item
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P2892 ?cui.
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {   
    ?item wdt:P2892 ?cui.
}
```